# Label spreading for classification/clustering problems

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, clustering, semi-supervised-learning

I have a question regarding [label propagation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelPropagation.html) and [label spreading](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelSpreading.html) semi-supervised algorithms. I am working on building a look-alike model to identify marketing personas. Using supervised learning algorithms is getting quite complicated as it takes a lot of time to run. And using unsupervised learning is quite complicated as well, as we need to specify "k". I am unsure of how to automate this process for new datasets. I need a middle ground machine learning algorithm suggestion that has lower time complexity and is reliable for new datasets.

So my question is: Can I use a graph-based semi-supervised machine learning technique to classify my dataset into personas? Specifically, [label propagation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelPropagation.html) and/or label spreading?

Please let me know your thoughts and any other suggestions that you may have. Thanks in advance!